# How to Install old version go-vim plugin

Tags: go, vim-plugin

I am a new golang developer. My company uses go 1.10.2, and I hit following error during installing vim-go

```
Error installing golang.org/x/tools/cmd/gopls: # golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/source^@../../../golang.org/x/tools/internal/lsp/source/symbols.go:232:18: ti.EmbeddedType undefined (t
ype *types.Interface has no field or method EmbeddedType
```

It turns out due to the old go version. https://github.com/fatih/vim-go/issues/2246, https://github.com/golang/go/issues/31864. Since upgrade go version is not an option, the only choice I can think of is to install an old version vim-go that supports go 1.10.2. But I am not sure how to do so. 
This is how I install vim-go now:

```
git clone https://github.com/fatih/vim-go.git ~/.vim/pack/plugins/start/vim-go
```

then open up vim and run `:GoInstallBinaries` (where above error show up)

Any suggestions would be great. Since I am neither a vim nor a go person before, more details would be appreciate!

Comment: Clone the repo and checkout to desired commit not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by cloning the repo and checkout to an old commit

Answer (score 0):

You should try goenv it support multiple version of golang.

Here is the installation guide

https://github.com/syndbg/goenv/blob/master/INSTALL.md

And after installation you can choose and install any version from the list.

Just by typing..

```
goenv install 1.10.2
```

Comment: @user1269298 does this help?

Comment: I do not have problem on install multiple version go.  Зелёный 's suggestion sounds reasonable, I will start with that.